# Signature pad for Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, digital-signature, signaturepad

I am looking for a Signature pad to be used in my Xamarin forms application (Portable).

I have tried https://github.com/aritchie/acr-xamarin-forms/tree/master/Acr.XamForms.SignaturePad.Droid

But was unsuccessful in implementing it.

Any link or tutorials to implement it would be very helpful.

Thanks
Rao

Comment: https://github.com/xamarin/SignaturePad

Comment: Hi Jason, I have added the nuget package for it. do I have to do this for each platform? can i use it in xamarin forms. As described i added a nuget package and tried to add the package in the the mainpage.xaml.cs 'using SignaturePad;' it is errors. could you suggests the steps to be followed

Comment: Yes, install in both the shared and platform projects.  The documentation clearly states it works with XF.  There are sample apps in the repo you can look at for more help